# Conditional Statement within Loop

Tags: vba, conditional-statements

What am i doing wrong? I want to create pdf files of a tab that runs through a list in column A from a different tab. Meanwhile, I want it to refer to the value in column CH to see if it is greater than 0 and if it is so save in a specific folder. If not, save in another folder.

Help is greatly appreciated as I can't find a solution and have been stuck for hours. Thanks!

Code:

```
Sub Generate_PDF_Files()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Table").Activate
Range("A7").Activate

Set r = Range("CH7:CH185")
With ActiveSheet
    For Each erange In .Range("CH7:CH185")
        If erange.Value > 0 Then
            Sheets("Att A").Select
            ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
                "L:\Mike89\Violations\" & X & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
         End If

         If erange.Value = 0 Then 
             Sheets("Att A").Select
             ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
                 "L:\Mike89\No Violations\" & X & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                 IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False,OpenAfterPublish:=False
         End If

     Next

     Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "STOP"
         X = ActiveCell.Value
         Range("DLR_NUM") = "'" & X

         Sheets("Table").Activate
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
     Loop

End with
End Sub
```

Comment: You code is missing an `End With`

Comment: @litelite *and* proper indentation, just as importantly (I approved that edit ;-)

Comment: you'd better post some relevant examples of involved sheets. you're writing about running _"through a list in column A"_ of which I cannot see a sign of. Furthermore you're referring to `X` before you define it by the end of the loop

Comment: Added "End with" before "End Sub" but still not working. What do you guys mean by proper indentation? Tried posting a picture of the referenced cells, but I don't see that functionality.

Comment: Basic troublelshooting help requirements - identify error message or symptoms of "it's not working" and the line causing any error

Comment: @Mike89 I don't see that you _"Added 'End with' before 'End Sub'"_. Do it in your post too.

Comment: This just seems to save the same sheet "Att A" (under different filenames) multiple times to one of two folders ?

Comment: @Mike89 - Proper indentation refers to the *code*.  See [this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39129010/3) that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Generate_PDF_Files()

    Dim c As Range, X, fName As String, shtAtt As Worksheet

    Set shtAtt = Sheets("Att A")

    For Each c In Sheets("Table").Range("CH7:CH185").Cells

        X = c.EntireRow.Cells(1).Value
        If X = "STOP" Then Exit For

        c.Parent.Range("DLR_NUM") = "'" & X

        fName = "L:\Mike89\" & IIf(c.Value = 0, "No Violations\", "Violations\") & X & ".pdf"

        shtAtt.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=fName, _
                      Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                      IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps I did something wrong, but it is giving me a run-time error saying "Method range of object_worksheet" failed ant it highlights "shtAtt.Range("DLR_NUM") = "'" & X" within the code when I try to debug.

Comment: Is there a range with that name on the sheet "Att A"?

Comment: I created a list of values in another tab and used data validation to call the drop-down list "DLR_NUM"). This is in the "Table" tab and not the "Att A" tab.